# Individual nested subdocument Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm Trying to embed a subdocument into my main document,like this:

This is the main document.js

```
var mongoose = require('../../db/mongodb.connector'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

require('./document.model');
var Document= mongoose.model('Document');
require('./alert.model');
var Alert = mongoose.model('Alert');

    var userSchema = new Schema({
        name:        { type: String }  
        created:     { type: Date, default: Date.now()},
        alerts:      {type: Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Alert'},
        documents:   [{type: Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Document'}],

    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

This is the embed document.js

```
var mongoose = require('../../db/mongodb.connector'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;


var alertsSchema  = new Schema({
    push:               {type: String, default: "true"},
    email:              {type: String, default: "false"},
    sms:                {type: String, default: "false"}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Alert', alertsSchema);
```

When I Insert a new User document like this:

```
exports.insertUser = function (userData, res) {

        var user = new User({
            name: userData.name,
            alerts: {push: "true", email:"false", sms: "false"}

        });

        user.save...

...
```

The returned data is this:

```
{ name: 'name',
  documents: [],
  created: 2017-04-14T10:22:05.612Z
}
```

The problem is that I don't know if I'm doing correctly the sintax of embed document because the insert doesn't return any error but the alerts object doesn't appear into the inserted new document.

What would be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You need to first save the alert document and then use its id in the user document.

```
let alertDoc = await new Alert({push: "true", email:"false", sms: "false"}).save();

// now use the id in the user doc
await new User({name: userData.name,alerts: alertDoc._id }).save()
```

In case you want to embed the whole document instead of just storing the ref. You could modify schema of user model. Define your schema like this.

```
var alertsSchema  = new Schema({
    push:               {type: String, default: "true"},
    email:              {type: String, default: "false"},
    sms:                {type: String, default: "false"}
});
....

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name:        { type: String }  
    created:     { type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    alerts:      alertsSchema,
    documents:   [{type: Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Document'}],
});
....

// now this should work
var user = new User({
    name: "<some name>",
    alerts: {push: "true", email:"false", sms: "false"}
});
```

Comment: But I want to embed the full object into the main document not their ref. The reason of use the refs into the main model is for clean the code. What would be the correct way to import the schema of separate documents to the main document?

Comment: Is there any way to maintain the schema of alert in other file and then import into the userschema file?

Comment: You could define one schema per file and then export them. This way you could import schema from other files and use them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small issue in `userSchema`. From your schema definition, it looks like you want to store only references to `alerts` and `documents`. The right syntax here would be `alerts: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Alert'}`. Please notice that extra **Types** in it.

Another issue here is, you are trying to store complete `alert` object inside `user` document. Mongoose can't allow that, as in your schema, you have told mongoose to save only references to the `alert` document. So what you need to do here is, create an `alert` document, get it's _id and then store it in `alert` field of `user` document.

Whenever you want to fetch the complete user schema, you can just [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) `alert` and `documents`.

Hope this answer improves your understanding of how mongoose schema works.